# 'Ambiguous argument" due to whitespace in filename?

Tags: git

I want to remove a huge ISO file from the git repository. it still resides inside the .git folder and I read that I need to "rewrite history" to remove it from there. Therefore, according to the official API, I must use the following command:

```
 git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f 
 ZeusSRC_Hardware_RPi_image_Raspberry Pi_außen_20.05.2019.zip'
```

As you can see, the filename does contain a whitespace. When executing the command, I get the following error:

```
  fatal: ambiguous argument 'ZeusSRC_Hardware_RPi_image_Raspberry': 
  unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I'm pretty new to this and so I dont really know what might cause such an error. My first guess was the whitespace, since the error message also "stops" the filename at the whitespace. And if it truly is the whitespace, what can I do to circumvent this error?

Comment: try with quotes? "file name.zip" ?

Comment: Well, there already are quotes, the ' ' ones, but I'll try

Comment: These quotes that you are talking about are for the command itself not for the filename

Comment: Thanks, I got one step further, will open a new thread for the next problem...^^

Comment: Or escape the space with a backslash like `file\ name.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the filename into quotes "file name.zip", else the command will think that it is a new argument after the space.